# Why do we need the extra assertion in this question?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

Proposition: Let $2^i$
  be the highest power of 2 dividing m, let a be odd and assume that $x^{m}
  \equiv
  a\space (mod\space  2 ^ {2i+1}$
 ) is solvable. Then $\forall$
 $j \geq$
  2i + 1, $x^{m}
  \equiv
  a (mod\space 2^{j}
 )$ is solvable.

I am seriously struggling to understand why the proof below does not work for p = 2:

Proposition: Let p be an odd prime, $p \nmid
  a$, $p \nmid$
  m. Then if $x^{m}
  \equiv
  a $(mod p) is solvable, so is $x^{m}
  \equiv
  a (mod\space p^{j}
 )$, for$ j \geq
  1$.

Proof: By induction. If j = 1, it is trivially true. Suppose it is true for j > 1. Let $x_{j}$
  be such a solution, and choose $\beta$
  to be the unique integer such that $mx_{j}^{m-1}
 \beta
  \equiv
  (a - x_{j}^{m}
 )/p^{j}$
  (mod p). This is possible as $(a - x_{j}^{m}
 )/p^{j}
  \in
  \mathbb{Z}$
  by assumption, and $p \nmid
  mx_{j}^{m-1}$
 . Then $x_{j+1}
  := x_{j}
  + \beta
 p^{j}$
  is such that:

$ \;
  \begin{array}{ccc}
x_{j+1}^{m} & = & \sum_{k=1}^{m}\dbinom{m}{k}x_{j}^{k}(\beta p^{j})^{m-k}\end{array}$

and by taking congruences we see that $x_{j+1}^{m}
  \equiv
  x_{j}^{m}
  + mx_{j}^{m-1}
 p^{j}
 \beta
  (mod \space p^{j+1}
 )$. By our choice of $\beta$
 , $mx_{j}^{m-1}
 p^{j}
 \beta
  \equiv
  a - x_{j}^{m}
  (mod \space p^{j+1}
 )$, showing $x_{j+1}$
  is a solution to the equation $x^{m}
  \equiv
  a (mod\space p^{j+1}
 )$, hence the result.$ \square$

It would be much help if someone could explain what goes wrong in this proof when p = 2, I kinda need this result for the essay I have been writing for a year! Cheers